# external hard drives won't mount

Tags: external-hdd

Ubuntu Studio 22.04 stopped mounting 2 of my 3 external hard drives. Using Dolphin file manager. I've uninstalled reinstalled dolphin but still won't mount the hard drives.Somewhat a newbe here. An error occurred while accessing 'Seagate Expansion Drive', the system responded: `The requested operation has failed: Error mounting /dev/sdb2 at /media/grocker/Seagate Expansion Drive: Unknown error when mounting /dev/sdb2`.

Comment: Using a terminal window (`Ctrl-Alt-T`), `sudo fdisk -l` (enter your login password when prompted) will show you information about the partitions. `sudo journalctl  -b 0 /dev/sdb` to see what the system is doing with the disk. You can force a file system check at the next boot with `sudo touch /forcefsck`, and bring on the next boot by `sudo shutdown -r now`. Please [edit] your question to add whatever information you get. Do not use Add Comment.

Comment: Have these partitions checked: the file systems may be damaged, and possibly quite badly since they even won't mount anymore.